# Combining multiple drives into one volume

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

We currently have a dedicated server with 3 SSD drives. We noticed we have actually deployed the OS on a single drive and the other 2 are currently not being used. However, this disk is almost full:

```
/dev/md2         91G   83G  3.0G  97% /home
```

The logical solution here would be combining the capacity of all three drives (3 x 120 GB) and turn them into one volume. What's the best way to do this?

Unfortunately, reinstalling the OS or the like is not an option for now.

The server is running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. I found LVM, but are yet to find out if this is the best solution.

As requested:

```
root@hv01:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G  2.5G   16G  14% /
devtmpfs         16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            3.2G  572K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G   24K   16G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md2         91G   84G  2.6G  98% /home

root@hv01:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]     [multipath] [faulty] 
md1 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sda1[0] sdb1[1]
  20478912 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

md2 : active raid1 sdc2[2] sda2[0] sdb2[1]
  96211904 blocks [3/3] [UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Put the drives in RAID-0, reinstall your OS afterwards. Oh reinstalling is not a option... Nevermind.

Comment: @Alex Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't RAID 0 support up to 2 drives?

Comment: Minimum is 2 drives.

Comment: @Alex Ok, thanks. As you mentioned it wouldn't be an option but thanks for your help.

Comment: If the device really is /dev/md0 then it's likely mdraid annd so you CAN just add the other two. You'll then need to expand the FS to use them as well. (Warning, make sure you have backups, and keep updated backups as failure of _any_ of the drives will take the entire system down).

Comment: Your snipplet shows the `/home` partition being nearly full, not the root partition. Please post the output of `df -h` and `cat /proc/mdstat`, and we will very likely be able to help you with minimum pain.

Comment: @EugenRieck Done!

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/mdstat` makes it clear, that you created a 3-way mirror set (RAID1) for your OS (md1) and Home (md2). While this provides ample redundancy, it costs you a lot of space.

Since you are disk-bound only on `/home`, the easiest way is to do a bit of disk-juggling.

Caveat: Be advised, that a dead SSD at the wrong point in time will cost you ALL your files - back up and be prepared.

That said, I would proceed along the line of

- remove 2 mirrors from md2. This leaves you with a still usable system without any downtime, but 2 free partitions. `mdadm --remove /dev/md2 /dev/sda2 && mdadm --remove /dev/md2 /dev/sdb2`
- wipe all fs and RAID superblocks from these two. `wipefs --all /dev/sda2 && wipefs --all /dev/sdb2`
- Create a RAID5 out of these 2 partitions, using `missing` as the third. This will in fact create a temp RAID0, twice the size of the original partition (md3). `mdadm --create -n 3 --level=5 --bitmap=internal /dev/md3 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2 missing`
- Add this RAID5 to the original md2 as one mirror and wait for the resync to complete `mdadm --add /dev/md2 /dev/md3` **WAIT FOR THE SYNC OR LOSE YOUR DATA!**
- Remove the last original mirror from md2, leaving it with a single leg, the newly created md3 `mdadm --remove /dev/md2 /dev/sdc2`
- Grow md2 to use all of md3 `mdadm --grow --size=max /dev/md2`
- Resize the file system to use all of md2 **THIS DEPENDS ON THE FS USED**
- wipe FS and RAID superblocks from this last partition `wipefs --all /dev/sdc2`
- Add it to the RAID5 and wit for resync to finish. `mdadm --add /dev/md3 /dev/sdc2`

You now have a mirror set with only one mirror, which in itself is a RAID5, double the initial size. This seems like quite a good balance between redundancy and size.

The nice part: You don't experience any downtime - all of the above steps are available while using the file system.

Comment: Thanks! For me, this sounds like algebra, though. Do you perhaps have a reference to some kind of guide?

Comment: There won't be a guide covering exactly this scenario - it is highly unusal, and I suspect it stems from soemthing not fully understood at the original setup. I will try and add the commands to my list.